# How do I make certain command arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So what I'm looking to do is make commands like ".help [command]" For example I have a ping command so I would like to run the command ".help ping" and then an embed would pop up showing a help embed for that command. My current command ".help" sends you a DM with the commands that I have entered into the DM Embed

help.js code

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  run: async(client, message, args) => {

    message.channel.send(":bow_and_arrow:  I've sent you a DM with a list of commands.")
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("PURPLE")
      .setTitle("Here is a list of all the bot commands!")
      .setDescription('You can use `.help <command>` for more information')
      .addField("Player Commands", "`.ping` | `.userinfo` | `.botinfo` | `.serverinfo`")
      .addField("Moderation Commands", "`.` | `.` | `.` | `.`")
      .addField("Admin Commands", "`.` | `.` | `.` | `.`")
      .addField("Misc Commands", "`.` | `.` | `.` | `.`")
      .addField("Developer Commands", "`.eval`")
    message.author.send(embed);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it something like this. Pretty much, im creating a collection and loading the commands (located in /commands/) getting their module.exports.help and setting it for the command handler. on a message I grab their message and try run module.exports.run (located in /commands/${command}). for the help command I check If they have arguments, if they do I attempt to get the command from the collection and return information about the command.

```js
// Command Loader (main file)

var fs = require('fs')

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
    if (jsfile.length <= 0) {
        console.log("Couldn't find commands.");
        return;
    }

    console.log(`Loading ${jsfile.length} commands!`);

    jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
        let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
        console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded!`);
        client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    });
});
```

```
// Client.on("message")
let prefix = "."
let [command, ...args] = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/\s+/g)

// Command handler

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
let commandfile = client.commands.get(command);
if (commandfile) commandfile.run(client, message, args);
```

```
// ./commands/ping.js
module.exports.run = async function (client, message, args) {
    message.channel.send(`Latency Is: \`\`\`${Math.round(client.ping)}ms\`\`\``)
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "returns latency of bot",
    usage: ".ping",
    aliases: ['.latency', '.ping']
}
```

```
./commands/help.js
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if (args[0]) {
        let command = args[0]
        if (client.commands.has(command)) {
            command = client.commands.get(command);
            var shEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("PURPLE")
                .setAuthor("______ HELP", message.guild.iconURL)
                .setDescription(`The Bot Prefix Is: .\n\n**Command:** ${command.help.name}\n**Description:** ${command.help.description || "No Description"}\n**Usage:** ${command.help.usage || "No Usage"}\n **Aliases** ${command.help.aliases || "No Aliases"}`);
            message.channel.send(shEmbed)
        }

        if (!args[0]) {
            message.delete();
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Help Command", message.guild.iconURL)
                .setColor("PURPLE")
                .setDescription(`${message.author.username} I've Sent You A DM! Check It Out`);

            let sembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("PURPLE")
                .setAuthor(`_______ HELP`, message.guild.iconURL)
                .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setDescription(`These are the avaliable commands for the _______\n the bot prefix is .`)
                .addField(`commands:`, `YOUR COMMANDS_HERE`)
                .setFooter(`_______ Version: ${version}`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
            message.channel.send(embed).then(m => m.delete(10000));
            message.author.send(sembed);
        } 
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "help"
}
```